# Solid is not an ambiguous base of sphere

Tags: c++

How can i fix this error,because i never met this error before.Can you help me?

```
class Solid
{
public:
    virtual void input()=0;
    virtual void output()=0;
    virtual float area()=0;
};
class Cylinder:public Solid
{
protected:
 float r,h;
public:
    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Radius:";cin>>r;
        cout<<"Height:";cin>>h;
    }
   float area()
    {
        return (2*3.14*r*r)+(h*(2*3.14*r));
    }
   void output()
    {
        cout<<r<<"\t"<<h<<"\t"<<area()<<endl;
    }
};
class sphere:public Solid,public Cylinder
{
public:
     void output()
    {
        cout<<r<<"\t"<<area();
    }
    float area()
    {
        return 2*3.14*r*r;
    }

};
int main()
{
    Solid *a;
    Cylinder c;
        a=&c;
        a->input();
        a->output();

   sphere h;
        a=&h;
        a->input();
        a->output();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sphere` inherits from `Solid` in two ways: directly, and indirectly via `Cylinder`. Since the inheritence is non-virtual, this means it contains two distinct `Solid` sub-objects, making the conversion to `Solid` ambiguous.

In this case, the solution is very simple: a sphere isn't a cylinder, so `sphere` shouldn't inherit `Cylinder`.